# osx terminal clear command queue

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, osx-yosemite

I carelessly entered the up arrow followed by a return symbol while running a lengthy process in terminal. If I don't intervene the process will start over, clearing the results of the previous run. Is there any way I can clear terminal's command queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "queue" may not have been read yet...

If the process (and shell) honor job-control, then you could try suspending the process temporarily (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) and resuming it (e.g., `%1`).  For this situation it is *common* (but not required) that on resuming the process the pending input on the terminal is discarded.

Comment: Are there cases where Python interacting with a custom C extension would not honor job control?

Comment: If you didn't start the process from a shell, e.g., if you ran something that created a subprocess displaying onto a terminal, that may not honor job control.  (Offhand I don't recall shells without job control, but that's something to keep in mind).